# md5 random name generator

Tags: php, md5

i don't know much about md5 so ill cut to the chase. On my image hosting site, when you upload a image it automatically gives it this looong md5 name. How do i make it shorter?
The names are like: 786a350023162842f7bb879bcc9aa560 i need them to be like: zl34s3

Heres the code:

```
//set the file name
            $filename = $file_array['name'][$i];
            $extension = get_file_extension($filename);
            $new_file_name = 'original-' .md5(rand(1000, 9999999) . $filename). '.' . $extension;
```

What about another system for me to use? is there one out there?

Comment: Can't you just use substr for that?

Comment: You don't. MD5 is always long, that's the point of it.

Comment: `uniqid()` will give you 13 characters, you can shuffle that and extract 6, but always check for a dup in the DB first. Why isn't MD5 an option? Seems fine, why the restriction?

Comment: If you MUST use md5, which outputs 128 bits, but you want to make the names shorter and you care only a little about collisions (which you must not since you're using MD5 instead of a secure hash), then you could break the md5 into parts and xor each part against the next... But I think a better solution is to find a different hashing scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to cut the first 6 characters of `md5`

```
substr(md5(rand(1000, 9999999)), 0, 6);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/m7wfGin6)

**Edit**

```
$new_file_name = 'original-' .substr(md5(rand(1000, 9999999)), 0, 6) . $filename . '.' . $extension;
```

Comment: why not just use the value of `rand` without passing it through a hash function?

Comment: @akonsu Because OP wants 6 characters of hash. :)

Comment: because, someone may have the same image name

Comment: if someone has the same image name then md5 won't help. because your `rand` can collide with another `rand`.

Comment: @user2578419 You should be specific with your error. We are not mind readers who can read your problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Im not good with php also, so if im probobly adding it in wrong.

Comment: @user2578419 If your problem is solved, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way, MD5 is a hash, you don't choose the size for it! You can make your own like function to make a checksum. You can take a piece of the MD5 with the substring function!

Comment: Ok, so how do i just make it lets say 7 chars?

Answer (score 0):

use another naming scheme, for example, use the user name and a timestamp as a part of the name. or use separate subdirectories for each user and just put timestamp into the name. there are endless possibilities.